# MySQL - Querying is taking too long on other system. How to speed up? MySQL configuration

Tags: php, mysql, time, configuration, mariadb

I have a problem with SQL query which executes fast on one system (Windows, XAMPP) and slow on the other (Ubuntu). Is MySQL setup a problem, if so how to setup MySQL?
I tried setting up my.cnf on Ubuntu with no success.

The SQL query is executed in phpmyadmin:
`SELECT id_dev, d.date_add  FROM dev_data as  d  WHERE date_add=(  SELECT MAX(date_add) FROM dev_data  WHERE id_dev = d.id_dev)`

On Windows with XAMPP - Apache/2.4.38 (Win64), PHP/7.3.3 ,  10.1.38-MariaDB:
The query took **0.0000 seconds** to complete.

On Ubuntu with Apache/2.4.29 ,MySQL, 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1,  PHP: 7.3.19-1:
The query took **19.7 seconds** to complete.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have index on date_add and id_dev columns in both databases?

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors. Like memory (settings) of MySQL server (more, could mean more fits in the memory). Type of disk and of course the indexes Felippe Duarte is talking about. Could you provide us with the SHOW CREATE TABLE outpost on both servers?

Comment: The database is the same on Windows and Ubuntu. I did a database export from Windows and imported it on Ubuntu. The structure and content in both databases is the same. In both, I have in the database:: `ALTER TABLE dev_data    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_dev_data),    ADD KEY fk_dev_data_dev1_idx ( id_dev);` I don't have an index on the 'date_add' column. I even exported the opposite. I exported databases (structure and content) from Ubuntu to Windows and checked the query on Windows. Then the result is the same. On Windows, it runs very fast

Comment: From EACH server, post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE dev_data; (not the script used to create the table), B) SHOW INDEX FROM dev_data: (so we can see the index cardinality, C) the slow query; D) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (your slow query); for analysis.

Comment: `0.0000 seconds` means that the "Query cache" is turned on.  Run again, but this time, do `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query could benefit from the index:

```
create index ix1 on dev_data (date_add, id_dev);
```

Comment: hmm, but why on Windows the query takes 0.0 seconds and on Ubuntu more than 19 seconds?

Comment: It could be the database created was not created with the same indexes. Or, the table may not have the exact same data. Are you sure the database are identical on structure and content?

Comment: The database is the same on Windows and Ubuntu. I did a database export from Windows and imported it on Ubuntu. The structure and content in both databases is the same.
In both, I have in the database::
`ALTER TABLE dev_data
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_dev_data),
   ADD KEY fk_dev_data_dev1_idx ( id_dev);
`
I don't have an index on the 'date_add' column.

I even exported the opposite. I exported databases (structure and content) from Ubuntu to Windows and checked the query on Windows. Then the result is the same. On Windows, it runs very fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id_dev, date_add
    FROM  dev_data
    ORDER BY  date_add DESC
    LIMIT  1;
```

And have `INDEX(date_add, id_dev)` -- in this order.

`0.0000 seconds` means that the "Query cache" is turned on and you had recently run it.

`19.7 seconds` means that there was no suitable index.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE dev_data` if you need further discussion.